# call javascript function located in main html from external js file

Tags: javascript, scope

sorry this problem might be resolved already, but I have not been able to find the answer.

I basically have 2 files:

**form.html** code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src=".../fileA.js"></script>
<title>BACKUP MONITOR</title>
<script>
    function getEvents()
    {
        alert("getEvents");
    }

    alert("in HTML");
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**fileA.js** code:

```
alert("in fileA");
getEvents();
```

**Question 1:**

I can't call getEvents() from fileA.js. Is there any way to do this?

**Question 2:**

Could I create a new Window from form.html and call getEvents() from there? please see code below:

New **form.html** code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>BACKUP MONITOR</title>
    <script>
        function getEvents()
        {
            alert("getEvents");
        }

        alert("in HTML");

        var w = window.open();

        var s = w.document.createElement("script");
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.src = ".../fileA.js";
        w.document.body.appendChild(s);

        w.alert("New Window");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

thank you very much

Comment: You need to call it from an onload event since you load the javascript file before you define the getEvents function. Another option is to move the getEvents function above the fileA.js

Comment: Why not just move your JS from in the document into its own .js file?  Then you can link to it easily, modify it simply, and reuse it easier if you need it later in life.

Comment: thank you NoGray, that worked for me, I have another question now. Can I create a new window from "form.html" add a js to it and call getEvents? I am going to edit my question to give an example

Answer (score 1):

Change the order in which your scripts load. Your external script `.../fileA.js` is loading before the `getEvents` function is defined in your embedded script. The call to `getEvents` in your external script can't succeed if the function doesn't exist yet.

**form.html** code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>BACKUP MONITOR</title>
<script>
    function getEvents()
    {
        alert("getEvents");
    }

    alert("in HTML");
</script>
<script src=".../fileA.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>BACKUP MONITOR</title>
<script>
function getEvents()
{
    alert("getEvents");
}

alert("1");
var eventArray = getEventArray();

var w = window.open();
alert("2");
</script>
<script src=".../fileA.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```